# Unsupported Media Type with Content-Type header?

Tags: angular, spring, http-headers, content-type

I'm getting an inexplicable error when I try to post an element by using the API of my backend. The API returns an error with code 415, related to Media Type:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 415 ()

My backend returns me this error:

> Resolved exception caused by Handler execution: org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: Content type 'text/plain;charset=UTF-8' not supported

EDIT: Error with Guru solution:

> Resolved exception caused by Handler execution: org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: Content type 'text/plain' not supported

The annoying thing is that I have added this header to my request:

> Content-Type: application/json

And the body is correctly parsed into JSON format.

I am using `Angular 5`, and my backend has been developed by using `Spring`.

**Angular client code:**

```
postProject(project: Project) {
    const headers: HttpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    return this.http.post('http://localhost:8443/projects', project.body(), {headers: headers})
      .map(response => response);
  }
```

where body method is:

```
body() {
    const object = {
      id: this.id,
      name: this.name,
      'num_execs': this.num_execs
    };
    return JSON.stringify(object);
  }
```

**Spring API code:**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<?> addLocation(@RequestBody Project project) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(esProjectService.save(project), HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

Where RequestMapping of the class is `/projects`:

```
    @RestController
    @RequestMapping("/projects")
    public class ProjectResource {

       @RequestMapping(value = "", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
       public ResponseEntity<?> addLocation(@RequestBody Project project) {
           return new ResponseEntity<>(esProjectService.save(project), HttpStatus.OK);
       }

       ... OTHER METHODS...
    }
```

Comment: Did you try adding `consumes` property to your spring method `RequestMapping`?  as in `@RequestMapping(value = "/methodName", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)`

Comment: @GuruprasadRao your solution fixed partially my error. Now, the output error is in my edited post.

Comment: Could you please add more details regarding your code? Your server method and also the way you send client request + request data in your network console..

Comment: @GuruprasadRao code added.

Comment: why `value = ""` in request mapping? How it would be mapped to `/projects`?

Comment: /projects mapping is declared above the class, so the methods has /projects map in common. The value of this method is "" because I don't want a custom map for this post method, its called as: http://localhost:8443/projects (see edited post)

Comment: But you are supposed to call specific method right? here `addLocation` is a method that you would be calling from angular client passing necessary data!

Comment: I have tried to modify the value of the method and the error is still the same...

Comment: You got to call the value then in your angular after `/projects`

Answer (score 0):

I've already gone through this, one way to solve it is to specify the type @RequestPart (value = "nameOfResource"  and  consumes = {"multipart/form-data"}

Do not forget to specify the name of Content in Angular.
I hope it helps.

Here is an example below:

```
RequestMapping(value = "/add", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = {"multipart/form-data"}, produces = "application/json")
        public ResponseEntity<?> add(@RequestPart(value = "image", required = true) MultipartFile image, 
                                     @RequestPart(value = "team", required = true) @Valid Team team, BindingResult bResult) {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In angular 5 `HttpHeaders` is immutable. Therefore, you should use it like this

```
let headers = new HttpHeaders({ 
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'X-XSRF-TOKEN': token
    });
```

or

```
let headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers = headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
headers = headers.append('X-XSRF-TOKEN', token);
```

Set the headers in this way and it should resolve your issue. I have put the sample code just to explain how you should add multiple headers. Don't put `'X-XSRF-TOKEN'` if you don't require it.

Answer (score 0):

I think the mistake comes from the fact that you want to consume application / json while you send plain / text.
I explain, in your service you specify

```
@RequestMapping(value = "", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
```

while in your front code you send plain / text

```
 return JSON.stringify(object);
```

Just delete the JSON.stringify call and return the json object and all is well.

Change

```
body() {
    const object = {
      id: this.id,
      name: this.name,
      'num_execs': this.num_execs
    };
    return JSON.stringify(object);
  }
```

to

```
body() {
    const object = {
      id: this.id,
      name: this.name,
      'num_execs': this.num_execs
    };
    return object;
  }
```