# Request content type - Spring throwing Exception under Internet Explorer 11

Tags: java, angular, spring, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

I have web application with Angular6 and Spring4. Under Internet Explorer while reproducing the issue I'm receiving

```
2019-04-26 13:10:20,574 ERROR [xyz] - exception: Content type 'text/plain;charset=UTF-8' not supported
```

In any other browser it works as it should, but not in the IE 11.

I'm using special class to log error above, because otherwise it would not hit our endpoint. *"ControllerErrorHandlers.java"*

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ControllerAdvice;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ExceptionHandler;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;

@ControllerAdvice
public class ControllerErrorHandlers {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(EventControllerErrorHandlers.class);

    @ResponseBody
    @ExceptionHandler(HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException.class)
    void mediaTypeExceptionHandler(HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException e) {
        LOGGER.error("exception: {}", e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Bean configuration to allow only json:

```
        class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter">

        <property name="supportedMediaTypes" value="application/json" />
```

Any thoughts? There is another posibillity that somehow Angular is misbehaving, only while testing it it Internet Explorer?
How can IE/angular needs to be forced to send the correct media type?

Comment: Did you passed Content type: 'text/plain' somewhere in your code? If yes than it can cause this issue. you can try to pass 'Content-Type': 'application/json' to check whether it helps to solve the issue or not.Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48202258/content-type-text-plaincharset-utf-8-not-supported-for-post-request-in-angula and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48519194/unsupported-media-type-with-content-type-header?rq=1

Comment: That means your frontend code send a request with a "text/plain" content-type. Why is that? We can't know without your frontend code.